# How to send CustomerName and CustomerSurname from Controller to edit or create cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, entity-framework-6

I want to send CustomerName and CustomerSurname from Controller to edit or create cshtml but I am getting error as:

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CUSTOMERS_14601EA232CC1C78E8EEE3B8325EDF47D2BEC1CCBF414A98771B931D28B27715'
>   does not contain a property with the name 'CustomerName
>   CustomerSurname'.

**The Controler**

```
// GET: PAYMENT/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS, "CUSTID", "CustomerName" + " " + "CustomerSurname");
    return View();
}
```

**The CSHTML**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentCustomer, "PaymentCustomer", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("PaymentCustomer", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentCustomer)
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone knows how to use both column name as one? 
"CustomerName" + " " + "CustomerSurname"

**And when try to edit with controller/edit**

```
 // GET: PAYMENT/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            PAYMENT pAYMENT = db.PAYMENT.Find(id);
            if (pAYMENT == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS, "CUSTID", "CustomerName", pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer);
            ViewBag.PaymentLocation = new SelectList(db.LOCATION, "LOCID", "LocationName", pAYMENT.PaymentLocation);
            return View(pAYMENT);
        }
```

**Edit View:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentCustomer, "PaymentCustomer", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("PaymentCustomer", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentCustomer)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set the `Text` property

```
ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
  Value = c.CUSTID.ToString(),
  Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.CustomerName, c.CustomerSurname)
});
return View();
```

Comment: I update my question Stephen. Second controller didnt work.

Comment: show the view code of the second controller! and what is the error message you got??

Comment: Sorry Mahmoud, it is same controller with different action method. I update my questions and shows the view that didnt work

Comment: In create view and Edit view the "ViewBag.PaymentCustomer" parameter are different.