# How to generate IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and set the Text property in controller/Edit CudtomerName and CustomerSurname

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Does anyone knows how to generate IEnumerable and set the Text property in controller/Edit CudtomerName and CustomerSurname as shown below?

In Payment/Create controller I replace;

```
ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS, "CUSTID", "CustomerName");
```

with this:

```
    ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.CUSTID.ToString(),
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.CustomerName, c.CustomerSurname)
    });
```

and its working. But in Payment/Edit is:

```
ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS, "CUSTID", "CustomerName", pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer);
```

Both ViewBag.PaymentCustomer looks same. The Payment/Edit its also get 4th parameter as "pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer". I cannot use "pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer" in db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select...

I try this:

> ```
>         //ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS, "CUSTID", "CustomerName", pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer);
>         ViewBag.PaymentCustomer = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
>         {
>             Value = c.CUSTID.ToString(),
>             Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.CustomerName, c.CustomerSurname)
>         }), pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer);
> ```

And After build and run. I can see dropdown list and inside drop down list does not shows Customername and CustomerSurname. It shows "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem".

How do I do that?

Comment: How does this differ from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854197/how-to-send-customername-and-customersurname-from-controller-to-edit-or-create-c) and the accepted answer?

Comment: I explained in last question that in create view is worked but not the edit view. The "ViewBag.PaymentCustomer " parameter is different in both view.

Comment: What is not working? Its not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Stephen I explained in detail in my question.

Comment: Because it needs to be `...}), "Value", "Text", pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer);`

Comment: But this is an awful way of generating your dropdownlist. Simply use `ViewBag.CustomerList = db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { ..... }); and in the view use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PaymentCustomer, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CustomerList)`

Comment: Can you explain in details. Because I believe I set the value and text in db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select... !!!

Comment: Yes you did, but then your creating another (pointless) `SelectList` from the first `SelectList` but not setting the `Value` and `Text` properties of the second `SelectList`

Comment: Then where I put "pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer". I did what you said and get errors.

Comment: I have already shown where to put `pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer` - it comes after `"Text",` And what errors (we are not psychic). But read my other comment and do this correctly and strongly bind to your model property using `DropDownListFor()`

Comment: I got it. My problem was on the "Value", "Text". I forget to put the double punctuation mark. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to generate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` means Just visit the following link it will helpful for u

[Asp.Net MVC with Drop Down List, and SelectListItem Assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833652/asp-net-mvc-with-drop-down-list-and-selectlistitem-assistance)

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/05/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERS.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem {
        Value = c.CUSTID.ToString(),
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.CustomerName, c.CustomerSurname),
    }), "Value", "Text", pAYMENT.PaymentCustomer);
```

Comment: This is NOT my suggestion and its awful and pointless extra overhead! Its just `ViewBag.CustomerList = db.CUSTOMERS.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.CUSTID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.CustomerName, c.CustomerSurname);`